# Save and Load strings

Tags: android

I used Menu onOptionsItemSelect(MENU) to save and load strings like this

```
public  static String filename = "MySharedString";
    SharedPreferences someData;
String s;
 someData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
```

---

```
case R.id.save:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Samples saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = someData.edit();
            editor1.putString("ourString1", s);
```

and load like this

```
case R.id.load:

    s = someData.getString("ourString1", "Couldn't Load Data");
```

and it worked well...as android removed MENU button for many devices i made a new activity which extends MainActivity and I put in Save and Load button.

```
public void bSave (View v){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = someData.edit();
        editor1.putString("ourString1", s);
        editor1.commit();
```

and load

```
public void bLoad (View v){
        s = someData.getString("ourString1", "Couldn't Load Data");
```

For some reason it doesnt work, I repeat i made new activity ( `public class Menu extends MainActivity{` ) which i start as Intent and it wont save or load strings from MainActivity

Comment: show the initialization of someData

Comment: public static String filename = "MySharedString";                 someData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);

Comment: what does "not work" mean

Comment: it does not save or load strings, nothing is showed in LogCat,

Comment: I dont understand why it doesnt work, It works in MainActivity but it doesnt work in Class which extends MainActivity

Comment: Why are you using buttons? Whether or not the device has a physical Menu button the method onOptionsMenuSelected will ALWAYS be called, no need to do anything extra.

Comment: Some users of my application contacted me that they cant reach to the menu on some devices like galaxy tab 2...I tried using MainActivity.this.openOptionsMenu(); but it did not work for them

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using the button listener properly. check if you set android:onClick attreibute like

```
android:onClick="bSave"
```

Comment: are you getting any value in s?

Comment: When saving or when loading?

Comment: both time.. just check if the lines are reached

Comment: I just checked, No value in s

Comment: if the two methods are not called. then i find no other reason than my answer :(

Comment: I tried making Toast and it shows up when i click on the button, so that is not the problem

Comment: ok please post complete code of two methods and also the initialization  that you commented